# C++ Variable destruction

Tags: c++, memory-management, scope

Suppose I have this:

```
std::wstring str = std::to_wstring(100);
str = std::to_wstring(1000); // Is the previous str destroyed?
```

If I reassign the local variable to another variable, is the old one destroyed?

Comment: There is no memory leak if that is the question. operator= will handle the dynamic memory

Comment: Everything you've shown is automatic storage. There's no memory management to worry about.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks, just needed to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the previous `str` destroyed?

*Yes*. There is no memory management happening in the code snippet you shared, it's all automatic storage.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept the answer in 9 minutes when stackoverflow lets me

Answer (score 4):

The old one is the new one, only the members are copied. Consider a simple implementation of assignment:

```
struct foo {
    int value;
    foo& operator=(const foo& other) {
       value = other.value;
       return *this;
    }
};
```

After assignment `a = b;` the object `a` is still the same object. If `foo` manages a resource, the `operator=` of course has to account for that and you can safely assume that all standard containers are not broken.

Comment: Thank you aswell!

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, see [the Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You cannot write effective and efficient C++ code without a firm grasp on these three rules.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't remember when I needed more than the rule of zero.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Had to make a `vector` of serial port wrappers the other day. I see the Rule of Zero as the standard to which all classes should strive, but when you delve too deep the choice is either three, five, or [the Balrog](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @user4581301 actually I forgot all the RAII types I wrote, forgot to count them in, perhaps because in such cases I like to use them rather than "need to" ;) though for memory I rely on smart pointers and containers whenever possible

Comment: "`operator=` of course has to account for that" - which any properly implemented class, including all containers in the Standard Library, do - meaning this is safe, does not leak, and applies to e.g. `vector` and `list` and `map` and so forth also.