# Copying a vector into a vector member of a class

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector, assignment-operator

I have a class with a vector member.
I have accessors to set/get the value of the vector.

```
typedef vector<int> vint_t;

class MyVector {
  public:
    MyVector(const vint_t & v) : _vint(v) {};

    size_t set(const vint_t & v) {
        _vint = v;  // Will this leak memory in the old location of _vint?
        const size_t n = v.size();
        return n;
    }

    const vint_t & get() {
        return _vint;
    }

  private:
    vint_t _vint;
};
```

Besides the fact that `set` correctly sets the contents of `_vint` (verified with code below, `operator<<` suitably overloaded), **would `set` leak the memory at the old location of `_vint`?**

```
vint_t v1 = { 1, 4, 10, 2 };
MyVector mv1(v1);
cout << mv1.get() << endl;
vint_t v3 = { 8, 1, 4, 10, 2 };
mv1.set(v3);
cout << mv1.get() << endl;
```

Comment: `_vint` is still the same object only its contents get replaced. I remember a very similar question. Let me see if I can find it

Comment: Of course not; the stdlib is programmed sanely, so RAII and assignment just work and nothing will be leaked. My question would be why _would_ you think it might leak at all.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63944427/4117728

Comment: Unless you want to look like a newbie C++ programmer coming from Python _or_ you fully understand the rules for C++ reserved names, then I suggest that you steer clear of leading underscores.

Comment: In addition to what @PaulFloyd said. Some quotes about what the standard says about leading underscores: `— Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an
uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.` ,  `— Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in
the global namespace` , `Literal suffix identifiers (16.5.8) that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.`

Comment: @idclev463035818 - 1) that is still the same object, but the memory used may change. My guess was everything was correctly handled by the stdlib, but just wanted to confirm.
2) Most likely yes.

Comment: @underscore_d - As for "Why..." I guess what each one assumes is the "default behavior, unless proven contrary" is more of a philosophical question...
The facts have been discussed in the comments/answers, and there I see the benefit of the SO community.

Comment: @PaulFloyd - I just pulled an MCVE from inherited code.
I did not pay attention to the conventions, and still got a completely useful clarification.
I take the bullets, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it does not leak memory, this because the standard containers are programmed sanely.
The assignement, in this case, just call the copy constructor of each element of the vector on the "right of =" and copy it on the vector on the "left of =".
Before this kind of assignement the vector on the "left of =" call the destructor of all the object.

**So if a memory leak happens it's due to the leak on the object argument of the vector template.**

Answer (score 1):

> would set leak the memory at the old location of _vint?

No. The memory location of `_vint` didn't change in the first place. Furthermore, the assignment operator of `std::vector` is not specified to leak memory  (nor is any operation of any standard container).

Of course, if the objects stored in the vector were handles to some resource, then those would leak if the handle is removed without releasing the resources. In your example you've used arbitrary integer values, so they appear to not be resource handles.

Comment: you give the same answer that i gave 2 min before...

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t set(const vint_t & v) {
    _vint = v;  // Will this leak memory in the old location of _vint?
}
```

There is no way this can leak memory unless `std::vector` would be terribly broken. In general after `a = b;` the object `a` is still the same object. Only the value gets copied. You are calling `std::vector::operator=` which isn't broken.

Comment: Note that the location where `_vint` stores its data may change with the assignment.
The OP referred to that memory.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio you are the OP, no? `std::vector`s main purpose is to manage the memory for you. If it would do that in a way that is broken there would be no reason to use `std::vector`

Comment: That was my guess... but the question doesn't harm (I guess)

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio if you are not familiar already, this might help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 0):

Since `_vint` is an object, it doesn't "change location". Pointers don't change location either, but can cause memory leaks if you allocate extra memory via `malloc` or `new`.

In your example though, you are neither using pointers nor allocating new memory. If you aren't allocating new memory, there will be no memory leaks, you will be using only as much memory as necessary and all of it will be accounted for when exiting a scope (like a function). This does not account for indefinitely nesting scopes, e.g. recursive functions, but you are not working with those either.

The point is, you are working with an object and assigning a value to it. The value is changed, but there is no "old location". No memory leaks here.

Comment: Note that the location where `_vint` stores its data may change with the assignment.
The OP referred to that memory.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
_vint = v
```

This is a *copy assign operation*, so the content of `v` are **copied** to `_vint`, but you don't delete or create any object, so there is no possible leak of memory. Also, remember that leaks of memory mostly happen when you are working with pointers, and you are not.

Comment: Note that the location where `_vint` stores its data may change with the assignment.
The OP referred to that memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but I do see two dangers in this code.

First

```
size_t set(const vint_t & v) {
    _vint = v;  // Will this leak memory in the old location of _vint?
}
```

The function returns `size_t` but has no return statement. I would expect compilers
to complain about this. The function should probably return `void`.

```
const vint_t & get() {
    return _vint;
}
```

Use this with caution. You need to be careful that the lifetime of the `MyVector` object is not shorter than any reference returned by `get`. For instance, a short contrived example:

```
MyVector* mvp = new MyVector(v1);
const vint_t& vref = mvp->get();
delete mvp;
// ...
std::cout << vref << '\n'; // oh dear
```

Comment: I did have the return statement in my code (otherwise the compiler would complain, as you say). I must have mistakenly removed it from the OP. Fixed.